как добавить программу без интерфейса и консоли в трей?
есть файл main.pyw который не использует никакого интерфейса, я хочу что бы этот файл отображался в трее винды, и имел кнопку выйти/close,
подскажите как это сделать только не надо придумывать велосипед, просто скажите библиотеку и как это сделать

хм. «не надо придумывать велосипед, просто придумайте велосипед и расскажите, как его сделать».

Ну как бы трей и тем более кнопка в нём это по определению интерфейс. Тем не менее, для питона как раз есть pystray

@aleksandrbarakin обычно когда я задаю вопрос на stackoverflow мне отвечают что то типа: "напишите небольшой graddle код который будет создавать bat файл" и т.д. хотя надо было просто нажать 2 кнопки, поэтому  я так и написал

@andreymal благодарю
